# Getting only 1 standard error of mean bar in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, standard-error

I am creating a bar plot, plotting whether they are immunized by the percent. I would also like to put the standard error of the mean within the bar plots.

This is the dataframe I am using called *immunized*:

```
Sample.ID  freq   percent      immune       sd        SEM    
    M1      577   0.3656846   Immunized 0.05357279 0.03093027 
    M2      546   0.2728938   Immunized 0.05357279 0.03093027
    M3      546   0.2728938   Immunized 0.05357279 0.03093027 
    M1      109   0.7798165 Unimmunized 0.00000000 0.00000000
```

I am using ggplot to graph the figure

```
ggplot(immunized, aes(x=immune, y=percent)) +
   geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
   geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=percent+SEM, ymin=percent-SEM, width=.2))
```

[image]

I am not sure why, but I am getting multiple standard error of mean bars in the bars. Only want 1 error bar per bar. The Immunized should be + and - .03093027 and the unimmunized should be 0.

Comment: you have three values for immunised - hence three (two are overlapping) errorbars. If you want only one, you will have to pre-process the data.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have 3 different `percent` values for `immune=Immunized`. ggplot behaves best if each row gets one value.

Comment: Is there a method to be able to 1 value?

Comment: Afraid not-- you'll have to make a new table. I'd use the mean and SEM of all 3 `Immunized` samples.